# What's a good alternative for iWeb?

Tags: macos, website, iweb

I recently used iWeb to make my site, and it looks great, but it has two problems:

1. Horrible for business; apparently it's not friendly with web spiders
2. Won't allow me to publish easily via FTP because it insists on storing everything in a folder named the same as my site, so I end up having http://www.mysite.com/www.mysite.com/Blog/...

So I'm on the hunt for an alternative.  My specific needs are:

Mac compatible, ease of use, business (search engine-friendly), blog integration, did I mention ease of use?

Comment: By "ease of use" you mean "not diving into HTML/CSS etc."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sandvox](http://www.karelia.com/sandvox/) from Karelia software and [RapidWeaver](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/rapidweaver/overview/) are other popular, commercial website creation tools for Mac OS X.

[Nvu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvu) is free, cross-platform and based on Mozilla.

Of course Adobe has some offerings (DreamWeaver, Contribute) but they might be too complicated.

Comment: Nvu hasn't been updated in forever, but it was good for creating simple HTML pages.  I used it long ago for some eBay stuff. RapidWeaver lacks any detail at all on the included features. I'm trying Sandvox now...it looks good.

Comment: @Javoid There aren't that many alternatives, just like there aren't for iTunes, unfortunately. How's the evaluation going?

Comment: So far so good.  It appears my DNS change has propagated yet, so I can't upload the site.  However, the page creation is easy - nut more limited than iWeb.  I'm stuck with themes, and haven't figured out how to add extra images and text to pages yet.  I may need to try RapidWeaver after all.

Comment: Went back to iWeb.  :(  Sandvox isn't customizable enough, and I found out how to fix the domain name problem.

Comment: Too bad. Good luck anyway, maybe someone else has another idea.